# How does NUnit run a list of test files?

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

I have a list of .dll files. How to run them in NUnit?

I remember in Python files can be run like this

```py
suite = unittest.TestLoader().discover("./","*.py")
runner = unittest.TestRunner()
runner.run(suite)
```

Now I have a list of .dll files. Is there any way to run them like Python in NUnit?